# Looking external DB from a Spring-JPA project

Tags: spring, jpa

I have a project i am going to put beans with `@Entity` annotations into it, BUT the tables of related entities are going to be in an external database, i do not build the database on start up, it is going to be an external database. Is this possible? Can a Spring-JPA project connect, write and read, relate to an external DB which it did not build the tables from that Entity beans? Forexample i am going to `entityManager.save(myentity)` also i have an entity class in project: `@Entity class MyEntity{}`. Is this possible?  Can JPA or Spring know about entities even if they did not build database on their own?

Comment: I don't understand your concept of external database. Can you explain better please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You only need to configure your entities correctly.

### Spring Data JPA Database access

Spring JPA, also all of another JDBC based frameworks connect always to a local or external databases, I understand that you are thinking that database need to be created by the application, which don't in most of cases. You have options to create the tables or update the columns or foreign keys when the applications is under deploy, but what happens is that hibernate creates an script and execute on the existing database on hibernate template.

### The ORM concept

The ORM is the concept that provides the mapping and the OO view from Relational Databases. When you create a `@Entity class Example`, you are telling to the java that will be a table on your database that will existe a table named `Example`, or even better:  `@Entity @Table('TB_EXAMPLE') class Example` will make the relationship between the class `Example` and the `TB_EXAMPLE` table.

So, you don't actually need to worry about how the database was created, but how you will map your entity to reflect the tables on your code. Keep in mind that YOU MUST to provide the mapping on the entity and all the information to JPA execute operations. If the database already exists, you need to take a look on the columns and table names to do a correctly mapping on your entities.

Also, there is some tool to make the reverse-engineering to create the Java classes from an existing database. To do this, take a look on [Hibernate Tools for eclipse.](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html)

### Save, read, update and delete.

If you correctly map your entity to you database, you can perform all operations without any problem. In the example described above, calling `entityManager.save(example)` will create a entry on `TB_EXAMPLE` in your database. It's really doesn't matter which way this table was created, it may be created by hibernate script on deploy, or a existing database that was created in 2004.

You can take a look on [ORM here](http://www.hibernate.org/about/orm) and [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html_single/). It's the best way to fully understand all the concepts.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer but i do not need to create database from my application. I need NOT to create database, the database is existing. BUT i need read write to that database. Also i have entity class codes. But can i use JPA and Spring to read and write into a such database with entitymanager. SO far i feel like JPA and Spring manage databases only they create from `@Entity` codes, is the opposite thing possible? Without creating database tables can i use entityManager with @Entity class codes?

Comment: Yes, the opposite is possible. When you said: `Without creating database tables can i use entityManager with @Entity class codes?` I was to say no, because the table must exist on database to perform operations, did you agree?

Comment: Table was built by another project's JPA.

Comment: No problem! You can use normally!

Comment: Normally? How? Does JPA know the table names of external DB? For example my project do not build those tables and look them in an external database. I think i should put something on persistence.xml or spring s applicationcontext.xml to introduce the table names to my project's JPA.

Comment: Like I said, normally but since you need to do the corret mapping on entities.